# Variables $_SESSION

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una variable session llamada index que esta creada en otro archivo con el valor 1, Y sisque index es igual a 1 me muestra una respuesta `<H4>Respuesta</H4>`, y con un boton llamo a una funcion javascript que cambiar el valor de variable, que al recargar la pagina no debia mostrarme la respuesta, pero no me funciona mi codigo, segun yo tengo todo vien, **El problema esq sin usar el boton la variable ya inicia con otro valor**

```
<?php 
session_start();

function Main()
{
    if($_SESSION['index'] == 1){
    echo "<h1>Respuesta</h1>";} else {echo "Ya no se muestra la respuesta";}
}

Main(); ?>
<input type="submit" onclick="clickk();">
<input type="submit" onclick="clickb();">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickk() {
        alert('<?php $_SESSION['index'] = 1; ?>');
    }
    function clickb() {
        alert('<?php ; $_SESSION['index'] = 2; ?>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Desde el cliente no se pueden modificar variables del servidor. Tienes que usar otra petición al servidor para que esté lo modifique. Puedes hacerlo por AJAX o un enlace al archivo php.

Comment: Muchas gracias, te lo agradezco